# Is there a neater way to transform an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am trying to transform an array, with only one of the values changed. Is there a neater way to do it?

I have attached the code that I have tried. It works, however I am only changing the number of the contact object for each user so it feels a little redundant to go through every other value to create a new formatted array. How can I replace just the contact number without going through everything?

```
const users = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: {
      givenNames: 'SpongeBob',
      last: 'SquarePants',
    },
    contact: {
      email: '',
      phone: '+1 123-1231234'
    },
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: {
      givenNames: 'Patrick',
      last: 'Star',
    },
    contact: {
      email: 'test2@test.com',
      phone: '+1 123-123-1234',
    },
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: {
      givenNames: 'Eugene Harold',
      last: 'Krabs',
    },
    contact: {
      email: 'test3@test.com',
      phone: '',
    },
  },
];
```

My code:

```
guestList() {
  const formattedArray = this.getSelectedGuests.map(user => {
     var rObj = {};
     rObj.id = user.id;
     rObj.name = user.name;
     rObj.contact = {
        email: user.contact.email,
        phone: user.contact.phone.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, ''),
     };
   return rObj;
  });
  return formattedArray;
}
```

Output:

```
const users = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: {
      givenNames: 'SpongeBob',
      last: 'SquarePants',
    },
    contact: {
      email: '',
      phone: '11231231234'
    },
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: {
      givenNames: 'Patrick',
      last: 'Star',
    },
    contact: {
      email: 'test2@test.com',
      phone: '11231231234',
    },
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: {
      givenNames: 'Eugene Harold',
      last: 'Krabs',
    },
    contact: {
      email: 'test3@test.com',
      phone: '',
    },
  },
];
```

Comment: Read it: [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to copy object properties without explicitly copying them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only need to change a property inside `contact`, you can use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) with [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring), to extract `contact` from the rest of the object.

Now you can [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) the rest of the object into the new one, create a new `contact` property, spread the contents of the original `content` into it, and override the `phone` property.

```js
function guestList(getSelectedGuests) {
  return getSelectedGuests.map(({ contact, ...rest }) => ({
    ...rest,
    contacts: {
      ...contact,
      phone: contact.phone.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, ''),
    }
  }));
}

const users = [{"id":"1","name":{"givenNames":"SpongeBob","last":"SquarePants"},"contact":{"email":"","phone":"+1 123-1231234"}},{"id":"2","name":{"givenNames":"Patrick","last":"Star"},"contact":{"email":"test2@test.com","phone":"+1 123-123-1234"}},{"id":"3","name":{"givenNames":"Eugene Harold","last":"Krabs"},"contact":{"email":"test3@test.com","phone":""}}];

const result = guestList(users);

console.log(result);
```

If you need to do a lot of immutable transformations, you might want to consider [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction). Immer allows you to use simple mutating code, and it ensures immutability using [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

```js
const { produce } = immer;

function guestList(getSelectedGuests) {
  return getSelectedGuests.map(user => produce(user, draft => {
    draft.contact.phone = user.contact.phone.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '')
  }));
}

const users = [{"id":"1","name":{"givenNames":"SpongeBob","last":"SquarePants"},"contact":{"email":"","phone":"+1 123-1231234"}},{"id":"2","name":{"givenNames":"Patrick","last":"Star"},"contact":{"email":"test2@test.com","phone":"+1 123-123-1234"}},{"id":"3","name":{"givenNames":"Eugene Harold","last":"Krabs"},"contact":{"email":"test3@test.com","phone":""}}];

const result = guestList(users);

console.log(result);

console.log(result[0] === users[0]); // false - a new object was created
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/immer/dist/immer.umd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as long as you don't use a library exposing Immutable objects implementation, this is the kind of code you have to write. Depending upon the JS dialect you have access to, you can write slightly shorter code, but the buld is still there:

```js
guestList() {
  return this.getSelectedGuests.map(user => ({
    user.id,
    user.name,
    contact: {
        user.contact.email,
        phone: user.contact.phone.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, ''),
    }
  }));
}
```

If you want to work with immutability, I would strongly advise to have a look at something like [Immutable.js](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/) (probably the one with the most diffusion) or [Seamless Immutable](https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable) (which has far less diffusion, but I like it a lot).

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid visiting each user because you have to change each user's `contact` property.

> I am only changing the number of the contact object for each user so
>   it feels a little redundant to go through every other value to create
>   a new formatted array.

You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to copy object properties without explicitly copying them.

I also added hyphen `-` and whitespace character `\s` to the regex to get the desired output.

```js
const users = [{ id: "1", name: { givenNames: 'SpongeBob', last: 'SquarePants', }, contact: { email: '', phone: '+1 123-1231234' }, }, { id: "2", name: { givenNames: 'Patrick', last: 'Star', }, contact: { email: 'test2@test.com', phone: '+1 123-123-1234', }, }, { id: "3", name: { givenNames: 'Eugene Harold', last: 'Krabs', }, contact: { email: 'test3@test.com', phone: '', }, } ];

let result = users.map(user => ({
  ...user,
  contact: {
    ...user.contact,
    "phone": user.contact.phone.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}-\s]/g, '')
  }
}));

console.log(result);
```

In most cases, you shouldn't be concerned about creating new arrays because JavaScript and platforms it runs on optimize for such scenarios.

But if you want to modify the array in-place, you can use [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to do that.

```js
const users = [{ id: "1", name: { givenNames: 'SpongeBob', last: 'SquarePants', }, contact: { email: '', phone: '+1 123-1231234' }, }, { id: "2", name: { givenNames: 'Patrick', last: 'Star', }, contact: { email: 'test2@test.com', phone: '+1 123-123-1234', }, }, { id: "3", name: { givenNames: 'Eugene Harold', last: 'Krabs', }, contact: { email: 'test3@test.com', phone: '', }, } ];

users.forEach(user => {
  user.contact.phone = user.contact.phone.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}-\s]/g, '');
});

console.log(users);
```